# Change selected option of an HTML Select element and submit as if I click on it

Tags: javascript, select, html-select

I have a select with four option elements, and I want to change the value using javascript and then submit it, as if I click on that option.

```
<select name="MainContent_GVTrabajadores_length" aria-controls="MainContent_GVTrabajadores" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

This is my try but the problem is that it doesn't get the results like if I actually clicked on it (it just changes the value with no effect):

```
document.getElementsByName('MainContent_GVTrabajadores_length')[0].value = '100';
```

Comment: David, if you speak in spanish, you can consider post your question in [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Are there more JavaScript you tried to?

Comment: That's the only one

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `onchange` event as shows:

```js
// function that receives the selected value in your SELECT element.
function submitSelection (vlr) {
   alert("You will submit '" + vlr + "' selected value.");
   // Add the rest of our code for submit this value.
}
```

```html
<select name="MainContent_GVTrabajadores_length" aria-controls="MainContent_GVTrabajadores" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="submitSelection(this.value);">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the value the SELECT's value to "100" and then submit the form. You just need to attach the function to some event to trigger it or modify it to suit your needs.

```js
function submitMyForm() {
  document.getElementsByName("MainContent_GVTrabajadores_length")[0].value = "100";
  document.myForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <select name="MainContent_GVTrabajadores_length" aria-controls="MainContent_GVTrabajadores" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
  </select>
</form>
```